# Can I use X11 on the new 64-bit OS instead of Wayland?

Tags: xorg

My business is heavily dependent upon the remote display capability of X11.  Does the new 64-bit Raspberry Pi Operating System allow me to choose X11 instead of Wayland ?

Comment: Have you done any research on this, or looked at the RPi documentation?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#wayland

Comment: If my business was dependent on a Pi I would be sticking with Bullseye (at least until they get the bugs out of Bookworm).

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can select that using the `raspi-config` tool.

From a terminal window on your RPi, type the following:

```bash
sudo raspi-config
```

Once the `ncurses` dialog starts, you'll see something like the picture below. Select the "A6" option & follow the instructions.

[image]

Comment: I'm so glad they did that, I suspect Wayland is going to cause some people grief.