# Mac VNC client that supports Raspberry Pi 5 and rescaling?

Tags: vnc, macos

I'm trying to remotely connect to my Raspberry Pi 5 from an M1 Mac laptop.

The officially recommended client is [Tiger VNC Viewer](https://tigervnc.org/), which connects fine, but can't rescale the display at all.
This is a problem for a device that outputs 4K resolution viewing on a laptop screen.

- [Chicken of the VNC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/chicken/) hasn't been updated for years and doesn't work on M1 macs.
- [Remote Ripple](https://remoteripple.com/download/) doesn't connect to the Pi - gives an error
- MacOS's built-in Screen Sharing app won't connect - says "unable to communicate"
- [Screens for mac](https://edovia.com/en/screens-mac/) (demo version) failed to connect.
- [RealVNC Viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/) works, and scales, but is incredibly slow.

I'd prefer free, but willing to pay if necessary. What's my best option?

Comment: Not strictly VNC but you could try https://www.nomachine.com/  ...The only issue with that is I am pretty sure it is X11-centric and bookworm defaults to Wayland (brief search online implies they are moving to support it properly and it is available but may have some drawbacks).  However, you can opt for X instead via `raspi-config`: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/144867/5538