# Browsers are not opening in Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

Both browsers Chromium and Firefox are not opening in Raspberry Pi. I installed the Raspbian OS from Raspberry Pi Imager and all is working fine but browsers are not opening. I checked with my old memory card browsers are opening but on the new memory card, they are not working. I have reinstalled chromium but it is still the same. It seemed to be some graphics problem but all others are working fine.

[image]

I tried through terminal and it is giving like this:
[image]

Comment: I’m assuming you are using Pi OS Bookworm and connecting over VNC? There are issues with VNC discussed on the Pi forums. Turning of wayland in raspi-config might help. https://forums.raspberrypi.com/

Comment: @CoderMike Can you be more specific? I don't know much about it and I am using it through SSH.

Comment: There's a new display server backend ("Wayland") used with the GUI stack on Bookworm. The old one is X11, aka. Xorg or just "X".  You can switch back to the old one using `raspi-config`: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/144866/5538  Please let us know if this works.

Comment: @goldilocks It's not working.