# Raspberry Pi 4b display cuts out but is still on

Tags: pi-4, display, raspberry-pi-os

I recently got my hands on a Raspberry Pi 4b and am having trouble setting it up.
Whenever the pi boots up, it shows the rainbow screen followed by a black screen with a cursor that blinks 4 times before the display signal cuts out showing "No Signal" on my monitor. After this happens, I'm still able to ssh into the pi and I'm able to control it through the command line.

I've tried both Micro-HDMI output ports, 2 different monitors, 2 different micro sd's, and both the 64 and 32-bit versions of RaspberryPiOS (Debian Bookworm port) using both the RPi imager and balena etcher. I'm using a USB-C power supply that came with my school provided Dell Chromebook. It says it's 65W, but also says it's capable of 5V at 3A which is the same as the recommended power supply from Raspberry Pi.

I've honestly tried everything I could possibly think of, and I would really appreciate an outside perspective. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update:
I just tried using RealVNC Viewer (a 2nd time after it failed previously) to view the gui and it worked!!! I would still love to find out why it doesn't work when plugged into a monitor. I'm suspecting it's either something with the Pi's settings, or just the way my monitor works.

Update 2:
After playing around with the Pi through VNC Viewer and rebooting, the display miraculously works! However, now when I try to log in with the gui, it takes me to what seems to be a light blue polygonal screen saver with a white spiral thing in the middle. Pressing keys and buttons does nothing and there's nothing else to the gui. But hey, progress is progress.

Comment: I'm not a *GUI guy* - I run all my RPi headless, so I'm in a poor position to give advice. 2 suggestions: **1)** Identify which OS you're running (bullseye, bookworm, ???)  **2)** If you've not done it already, you should check the RPi ["official documentation"](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/). You may have to search a bit, but there's much info there, and it's mostly accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just edited my post to include the exact OS version (Bookworm). In the meantime I'm gonna try a few more things and look through the documentation.

Comment: Something you might try: Run `raspi-config` (from the CLI: `sudo raspi-config`), and try changing from Wayland to X. There's an [answer here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/144867/83790) that provides details. I've no idea if it'll help, but there seems to be several issues with Wayland.

Comment: try commenting out dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d in /boot/config.txt i had similar issue like you and it helped me.

Comment: @Seamus Your suggestion of switching from Wayland to X helped me (Rpi 4, 2GB RAM, running latest Raspbian 64-bit). Thank you!

Comment: @AndrásAszódi: Glad to hear that, and thanks for the feedback. You can click the "up arrow" next to my comment if you'd like to show positive feedback.