# Ras Pi OS Black screen after switching to X11

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, wayland

I have a new install of the current Pi OS (bookworm) and am having an issue getting my touchscreen to rotate. I think I identified Wayland as the problem and switched to X11 as detailed in this post:

[Can I use X11 on the new 64-bit OS instead of Wayland?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/144866/can-i-use-x11-on-the-new-64-bit-os-instead-of-wayland)

Now when I reboot I get a black screen with white underscore in the corner. Not sure what to do next. I know how to switch back to Wayland using SSH but I'd like to get X11 running. Any tips?

Comment: Are you an experienced X11 user? By that I only mean to ask if you know how to set up X11 to run.

Comment: If you REALLY want X11 run the Legacy OS (Bullseye). The Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm is only recommended for Pi4 & Pi5.