DPMS on Raspberry Pi 5?
I’ve got an RPi 5 onto which I installed Raspberry Pi OS a couple days ago. I can’t seem to get the display to power off (or even blank) when idle. Any attempt to use xset dmps results in:
$ xset dpms force off
server does not have extension for dpms option
xset:  unknown option force

I have libxext6 installed, and I've nabled screen blanking via rapsi-config, and rebooted. I also tried installing libkf5screendpms8, just in case.
There is no hdmi_blanking line in /boot/firmware/config.txt, although I’m not sure if there needs to be.
Note that setterm --powerdown 0 does work.
Is DPMS something that should be supported on RPi 5? My end goal is simply to have the display shut off after a few minutes of inactivity (ideally, only activity at the display, not via ssh).

Current versions of raspios use Wayland as the default GUI display server, which xset won't apply to: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/144866/5538

Having used setterm --powerdown 5,  so far it’s behaving more or less like I want.
